# Problem coming during product import using Magmi

Tags: magmi

I need to import a product with Magmi.

The import worked in old web site, but not in new website.

It's the same source file but the file is not imported.

In log file there is:

```
 Got error 'PHP message: PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 0 in /var/[...]/magmi/engines/magmi_productimportengine.php on line 1219\n
```

what can be the problem?

Thanks

Comment: is both site hosted in same server ?  also check all database credentials , configuration.....

Comment: Solved! There was a problem with a field. thanks

Comment: means you are telling some configuration problem , if so you can post an answer and accept it.....

Comment: the problem was in source file.

Comment: fine, glad that you found solution.....